# What would cause a property get on an interface to fail?

Tags: c#, properties, interface, xamarin-studio

I have an interface with a property, and a class that implements that interface.  I cast an instance of the class to the interface, then attempt to read the property and it doesn't retrieve the value.  Can anyone see why?

Interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int ObjectId { get; }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
     public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
...
Bar myBar = new Bar() { ObjectId = 5 };
IFoo myFoo = myBar as IFoo;
int myId = myFoo.ObjectId;  //Value of myFoo.ObjectId is 5 in Watch, but myId remains at 0 after statement
...
```

This is oversimplified, but essentially what I'm doing.  Why can I see the value of myFoo.ObjectId in the watch window, but the assignment to myId fails (value is 0 before and after assignment)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code - the only explanation is that either you're inspecting it on the breakpoint on the last line (which is infact before it executes), or you're inspecting the wrong variable. Put a `Console.WriteLine(myId)` at the end, and you'll see the value is indeed set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have manipulated the data on your watch through manual intervention or a statement that changed the value.

I did a quick test on your code in a Console Application and the value of myId is 5.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bar myBar = new Bar() { ObjectId = 5 };
        IFoo myFoo = myBar as IFoo;
        int myId = myFoo.ObjectId;

        Console.WriteLine(myId); // 5

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

interface IFoo
{
    int ObjectId { get; }
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I went back to my code, and renamed the variables to match my example so I could provide a screenshot and after renaming it started working as expected.  I think the problem might be that the myFoo object was named the same as the parameter in the constructor of the class I was working in (this.myFoo = myFoo).  It shouldn't have been in scope when my problem code was executed, but I can't think of any other explanation.  Thank you for your help!